# PyQt multi threading: program maybe crash while tracing a tree graph

Tags: python, multithreading, svg, graph, pyqt

I want to trace a node and all of it's child nodes in a tree graph from top to down, then change the color and status of all nodes, so I use `pyqt` to simulate this behavior.
There are two kinds of resident threads in run time:

- `ChangeColorThread()` - read the `coloring_queue` and change color and status of a node. `coloring_queue` contain the next node will be changed status and color.
- `TraceGraphThread()` - read the `waiting_queue` and trace all relative nodes. `waiting_queue` contain the next node will be processed.

The color of all status for nodes:
`init (no color) -> waiting (color = lightyellow) -> running (color = yellow) -> finish (color = green)`

I decide to create only one `ChangeColorThread()` thread and **max_number - 1** `TraceGraphThread()` threads in memory, because I think changing color/status is faster than tracing the graph.

This program has a problem: If I slide the horizontal or vertical scrollbar arbitrarily while tracing nodes, this program maybe crash. :(

[image: My Caption]

I'm not sure what the reason is, but I guess the bottleneck maybe using QGraphicsSvgItem.update() too frequently or processing xml string of the graph.
Do anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot!

The source code is below:

```
import re
import sys
import time
import logging
import random
import networkx as nx
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
from graphviz import Digraph
from queue import Queue, Empty
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtSvgWidgets import QGraphicsSvgItem
from PyQt6.QtSvg import QSvgRenderer
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *

class MyWindow(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.cfg = {}              # store all QGraphicsSvgItem() objects and their status (init -> waiting -> running -> finish)
    self.graph = nx.DiGraph()  # store the upstream/downstream of every nodes and help tracing
    self.viewer = QGraphicsView(self)
    self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
    self.scene.clear()
    self.viewer.setScene(self.scene)
    self.viewer.resetTransform()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    layout.addWidget(self.viewer)

  def closeEvent(self, event):
    global sys_close
    sys_close = True


class SvgItem(QGraphicsSvgItem):
  def __init__(self, renderer, id, node):
    super().__init__()
    self.id = id
    self.node = node
    self.setSharedRenderer(renderer)
    self.setElementId(id)
    bounds = renderer.boundsOnElement(id)
    self.setPos(bounds.topLeft())

  def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if self.id.find('node') != -1:
      self.trace_nodes()
  
  def trace_nodes(self):
    global window
    global coloring_queue
    global waiting_queue
    if window.cfg[self.node, 'status'] not in ['waiting', 'running']:
      coloring_queue.put((self, 'waiting'))
      waiting_queue.put(self)


class ChangeColorThread(QRunnable):
  def set_thread_name(self, thread_name):
    self.thread_name = thread_name

  def run(self):
    global svg
    global window
    global renderer
    global coloring_queue
    global sys_close
    while True:
      time.sleep(0.1)
      if sys_close == True:
        break
      if not coloring_queue.empty():
        event = coloring_queue.get(False)
        item = event[0]
        status = event[1]
        # color of all status:
        # init (no color) -> waiting (color = lightyellow) -> running (color = yellow) -> finish (color = green)
        window.cfg[item.node, 'status'] = status
        if status == 'waiting':
          color = 'lightyellow'
        elif status == 'running':
          color = 'yellow'
        elif status == 'finish':
          color = 'green'

        # change node color by replace xml string of svg graph
        if item.id.find('node') != -1:
          svg = re.sub('(<title>' + item.node + '</title>\n<polygon fill=")([a-z]*)(")(.{0,3000})(status: )([a-z]*)(</text>)', '\\1' + color + '\\3\\4\\5' + status + '\\7', svg, 1, flags = re.DOTALL)
          renderer.load(bytes(svg, encoding='utf-8'))
          item.update()


class TraceGraphThread(QRunnable):
  def set_thread_name(self, thread_name):
    self.thread_name = thread_name

  def run(self):
    global window
    global coloring_queue
    global waiting_queue
    global sys_close
    while True:
      time.sleep(3)
      if sys_close == True:
        break
      try:
        if not waiting_queue.empty():
          item = waiting_queue.get(False)
          node_name = item.node

          # simulate running something for 1 ~ 5 seconds then finish.
          coloring_queue.put((item, 'running'))
          time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
          coloring_queue.put((item, 'finish'))

          # process all the child nodes
          out_num = len(window.graph.out_edges(node_name))
          for n in range(out_num):
            out_node_name = list(window.graph.out_edges(node_name))[n][1]
            coloring_queue.put((window.cfg[out_node_name, 'item'], 'waiting'))
            waiting_queue.put(window.cfg[out_node_name, 'item'])
      except Empty:
        logging.info(f'TraceGraphThread error: {self.name} queue empty.')
        self.run()  # Queue empty exception may happend in the multi-threads program. If happend, rerun this thread.


def generate_svg(edges):
  dot = Digraph(comment='Test SVG Graph', format='svg', node_attr={'shape': 'record'})
  for i in range(len(edges)):
    lable_src = '{{node_name:|' + edges[i][0] + '|type}|{note1:|....................}|{note2:|....................}|{note3:|....................}|this is a test node\lthis is a test node\lthis is a test node\l|status: init\l}'
    lable_dest = '{{node_name:|' + edges[i][1] + '}|{note1:|....................}|{note2:|....................}|{note3:|....................}|this is a test node\lthis is a test node\lthis is a test node\l|status: init\l}'
    dot.node(edges[i][0], lable_src)
    dot.node(edges[i][1], lable_dest)
    dot.edge(edges[i][0], edges[i][1])
    window.graph.add_edges_from([edges[i]])
  return dot.pipe(encoding='utf-8')

logging.basicConfig(format="%(message)s", level=logging.INFO)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  waiting_queue = Queue()  # contain the next node will be processed
  coloring_queue = Queue() # contain the next node will be changed status and color
  sys_close = False        # it become True when colse the main window, then all threads will be interupted

  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = MyWindow()
  # edges tuple contains two columns: source node, destination node.
  edges = [('TEST_NODE_001', 'TEST_NODE_002'), ('TEST_NODE_002', 'TEST_NODE_A'),
           ('TEST_NODE_002', 'TEST_NODE_B'),   ('TEST_NODE_002', 'TEST_NODE_C'),
           ('TEST_NODE_002', 'TEST_NODE_D'),   ('TEST_NODE_002', 'TEST_NODE_E'),
           ('TEST_NODE_002', 'TEST_NODE_F'),   ('TEST_NODE_002', 'TEST_NODE_G'),
           ('TEST_NODE_002', 'TEST_NODE_H'),   ('TEST_NODE_002', 'TEST_NODE_I'),
           ('TEST_NODE_002', 'TEST_NODE_J'),   ('TEST_NODE_A',   'TEST_NODE_A01'),
           ('TEST_NODE_B',   'TEST_NODE_B01'), ('TEST_NODE_B01', 'TEST_NODE_B02'),
           ('TEST_NODE_C',   'TEST_NODE_C01'), ('TEST_NODE_C01', 'TEST_NODE_C02'),
           ('TEST_NODE_C02', 'TEST_NODE_C03'), ('TEST_NODE_D',   'TEST_NODE_D01'),
           ('TEST_NODE_D01', 'TEST_NODE_D02'), ('TEST_NODE_D02', 'TEST_NODE_D03'),
           ('TEST_NODE_D03', 'TEST_NODE_D04'), ('TEST_NODE_D04', 'TEST_NODE_D05'),
           ('TEST_NODE_D05', 'TEST_NODE_D06'), ('TEST_NODE_D06', 'TEST_NODE_D07'),
           ('TEST_NODE_D07', 'TEST_NODE_D08'), ('TEST_NODE_D08', 'TEST_NODE_D09')]
  svg = generate_svg(edges)
  #print(f'svg: {svg}')
  renderer = QSvgRenderer()
  renderer.load(bytes(svg, encoding='utf-8'))

  # get all id and node name from svg graph and draw items on screen
  root = et.fromstring(svg)
  for g in root.findall('.//{*}g'):
    id = g.get('id')
    node = g.find('.//{*}title').text
    if id != 'graph0':
      window.item = SvgItem(renderer, id, node)
      window.scene.addItem(window.item)
      window.cfg[node, 'item'] = window.item
      window.cfg[node, 'status'] = 'init'

  # create one ChangeColorThread() and max-1 TraceGraphThread() in memory
  pool = QThreadPool.globalInstance()
  max_thread = QThreadPool.globalInstance().maxThreadCount()
  run = ChangeColorThread()
  run.set_thread_name(f'Thread_0')
  pool.start(run)
  for i in range(max_thread-1):
    run = TraceGraphThread()
    run.set_thread_name(f'Thread_{i+1}')
    pool.start(run)
  
  window.show()
  window.viewer.horizontalScrollBar().setSliderPosition(0)                          # let the horizontal scrollbar at the left
  window.viewer.verticalScrollBar().setSliderPosition(-int(window.scene.height()))  # let the vertical scrollbar at the top
  sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: updating the GUI from another thread is a segmentation fault, you are only allowed to emit signals from threads.

Comment: but it's not updating entire GUI, it's only updating one object in the scene.

Comment: @CipheroChen Qt does not support GUI operations of any kind outside the main thread. Such operations aren't thread-safe, so you must always use signals to communicate between worker threads and the GUI.

Comment: @CipheroChen That's completely irrelevant. Even a single item is **part** of the UI, and *any* attempt to access *any* aspect of the UI from external threads is **not** safe.